# Remove JSON object from array

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I am using this to serialize my data to object in vb.net [Newtonsoft.Json](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json) But what I want to do, is to delete object from my event array. The first one (index 0).
I know that can create a class and a list, but the data I get is changing from call to call.

```
Dim msg As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)

Dim imgageInfo As Object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Object)(msg)
MsgBox(imgageInfo("event")(0)("settings").ToString)
```

Comment: which object do you want to delete? At the position 0 of the array?

Comment: I want to delete the first object in the event array

Comment: If you deserialize to a List its pretty simple to remove the one(s) you dont want.  I'm not sure `Of Object` is a good idea though.  Your 'chaning' comment just sounds like an issue of Scope.

Comment: What should i use instead of `Of Object` if I can not create a Class on my data?

Comment: Typically, you deserialize something to its Type so you can use the properties and methods defined for that Type.  Deserializing to `Object` hides/masks those methods and properties (unless you use late binding which requires `Option Strict Off`).  What you show is not much different than if you had used `JObject.Parse()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could deserialize the object into a dictionary and make adjustments to the array from there.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(msg);
```

Maybe a sample of your json would help.